# Writing Biopython output into csv

Tags: python, csv, bioinformatics, biopython

I am currently working on a class project that requires me to pull data from the NCBI website using biopython and writing it to a CSV file which I then analyze in R. I got all the data I need, but I'm not completely sure how to write it into a CSV file since we never covered it in class. Here is my code so far:

```
from Bio import Entrez, Medline

Entrez.email = "email.here"

handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed",  # database to search
                        term="Chan CS[Author] AND 2000:2017[Date - Publication]",  # search term
                        retmax=200 # Maximum number of results to return
                        )
record = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()

pmid_list = record["IdList"]
print(pmid_list)
```

Followed by

```
from Bio import Medline
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmid_list, rettype="medline", retmode="text")
records = Medline.parse(handle)

journal_dict = []
datep_dict = []
place_dict = []
for record in records:

    # retrieve journal titles 
    title = record['JT']
    journal_dict.append(title)

    #retrieve date published
    date = record['DP']
    datep_dict.append(date)

    #retrieve place published
    place = record['PL']
    place_dict.append(place)
# Close the efetch handle    
handle.close()

for title in journal_dict:
    print(title)
for date in datep_dict:
    print(date)
for place in place_dict:
    print(place)
```

And lastly, the part I am stuck on

```
import csv
```

I'm trying to get the csv file to look something like below

```
[ID, Journal Title, Publication Date, Place of Publication]
[123, Title1, Date1, Place1]
[124, Title2, Date2, Place2]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second block of code, your variable names talk about `dict`ionaries, but your they are actually `list`s:

```
journal_dict = []
datep_dict = []
place_dict = []
```

So, let's fix that (this will also be useful later when writing to CSV):

```
record_list = []
for record in records:
    record_dict = {'ID': record['ID'],
                   'Journal Title': record['JT'],
                   'Publication Date': record['DP']
                   'Place of Publication': record['PL']}
    record_list.append(record_dict)
```

Now let's write this list of dictionaries into a CSV file

```
import csv

with open('medline.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['ID', 'Journal Title', 'Publication Date', 'Place of Publication']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for record_dict in record_list:
        writer.writerow(record_dict)
```